# Primary server 'XYZ' can not write to shared drive during availability group configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, azure-vm

I am in a process of adding databases to availability group. In one of the steps it was asking "data synchronization prefferences" as shown below

[image]

I have put the mapped drive location path, which was FILESHARE created in azure portal.

Now availability group validation fails as shown below, it says "Primary server '[MYNODENAME]' can not write to shared drive during availability group configuration"

[image]

Update

IP for listener was wrong . issue resolved .

New Error

> The Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) resource control API returned error code 87.  The WSFC service may not be running or may not be accessible in its current state, or the specified arguments are invalid.  For information about this error code, see "System Error Codes" in the Windows Development documentation.
>   The attempt to create the network name and IP address for the listener failed. The WSFC service may not be running or may be inaccessible in its current state, or the values provided for the network name and IP address may be incorrect. Check the state of the WSFC cluster and validate the network name and IP address with the network administrator.
>   The attempt to create the network name and IP address for the listener failed. The WSFC service may not be running or may be inaccessible in its current state, or the values provided for the network name and IP address may be incorrect. Check the state of the WSFC cluster and validate the network name and IP address with the network administrator. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have proper access to the share and folder?

Comment: Yes it has the access . read write access

Comment: generally you have to have something to close to a Domain Admin account to create the Listener and IP address, you are actually updating DNS and AD at that point. Since this is all in Azure though they must have this all documented well. Start with your WSFC, run the validate to make sure it is totally healthy, and then attempt the AG set up. Sounds like your WSFC might have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PORT 5022 was not added to secondary node's firewall

After adding rule, it worked like charm

**This is how I found the solution**

Open command prompt

```
     Telnet NODE2 5022
```

This failed